# Spring Security Login issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security and have configured Spring Security in my Spring MVC application.

After submission of login page, I am getting the following error

`The requested resource (/j_spring_security_check) is not available.`

I am not able to understand this behaviour.

Please help.

**spring-security.xml**

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/appln/denied">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/appln/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/appln/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/appln/run" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/appln/common" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/appln/login"
                         authentication-failure-url="/appln/login?error=true"
                         default-target-url="/appln/run"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="AuthHandlr" />

    <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
                     logout-success-url="/appln/login" 
                     delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</security:http>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: A spring security config snippet (as well as the relevant web.xml one) would really help.

Comment: Have you checked your logs files? That message is frequently a sign that the server didn't start up cleanly. There should be a log error/stacktrace somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue.

In my loginpage.jsp , the action attribute was defined as

`action=../../j_spring_security_check`

I was playing with the above and changed it to

`action = /j_spring_security_check`

and it worked without any issues.

Although the issue is solved , can anybody please elaborate on why did the change in the path work.

Answer (score 0):

The form action can be 'j_spring_security_check'  or '/j_spring_security_check'.

This is a default in Spring-Security can not be changed.

Similarly the form fields have to be 'j_username' and 'j_password'