# How to configure different UserDetailsService beans for form and OpenID authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to customize authentication with spring security 3.1 to use both form and OpenID login.

Here is my spring-security.xml file:

```
   <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/login.htm" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginopenidfailed*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home.htm" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_CLOUD_USER')" />

    <form-login login-page="/login.htm"
        default-target-url="/admin.htm"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.htm"
        always-use-default-target="true"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout.htm" logout-success-url="/home.htm" />  
    <openid-login authentication-failure-url="/loginopenidfailed.htm">
      <attribute-exchange>
        <openid-attribute name="email" type="http://schema.openid.net/contact/email" required="true" count="2"/>
        <openid-attribute name="name" type="http://schema.openid.net/namePerson/friendly" />
      </attribute-exchange>
    </openid-login>
  </http>

  <!--Authentication Manager -->
  <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <authentication-provider ref="openIDAuthenticationProvider"/>
  </authentication-manager>

  <!--dao authentication provider -->
  <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder">
      <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" />
    </beans:property>
  </beans:bean>

  <!--openID authentication provider -->
  <beans:bean id="openIDAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="openIDUserDS" />
  </beans:bean>

  <!--openID UserDetail -->
  <beans:bean id="openIDUserDS" class="test.security.CloudOpenIDUserDS"/>

  <user-service id="userDetailsService">
    <user name="abdellah" password="32fe5bbf04adc744455c92fa7b71e9dca8ce729c" authorities="ROLE_CLOUD_USER" />
    <user name="guest"    password="35675e68f4b5af7b995d9205ad0fc43842f16450" authorities="ROLE_CLOUD_USER" />
  </user-service>

</beans:beans>
```

You can see that I have two provider elements in the "authentication-manager", one for each type of authentication. The OpenID provider is configured with a `UserDetailService` bean called `openIDUserDS`.

When I deploy the application, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is 

... Snip to root cause ...

Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id reference in <remember-me/> <openid-login/> or <x509 /> elements.
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.getUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.authenticationUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
    ... 95 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `<openid-login>` namespace element which will automatically try and look for a `UserDetatailsService`. Just adding other beans to the configuration won't make any difference by itself.

As the error message says, you need to supply an ID directly in the namespace element. Use the `user-service-ref` attribute (see the [namespace appendix](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-openid-login)):

```
<openid-login user-service-ref="openIDUserDS">
   ...
```

and remove the `openIDAuthenticationProvider` bean.

Comment: if i remove the bean openIDAuthenticationProvider ; so i remove it from the element <authentication-manager > ?

Comment: it seem to work good!!  but i have another problem when i log with form: The requested resource (/j_spring_security_check) is not available.

Comment: Please make an effort to search [when you have an error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083537/spring-security-login-issue). Both this and your original question have been covered before and you will save yourself a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception stacktrace indicates

```
nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id reference in   or  elements.
```

The problem is with the element -

```
  <user-service id="userDetailsService">
    <user name="abdellah" password="32fe5bbf04adc744455c92fa7b71e9dca8ce729c" authorities="ROLE_CLOUD_USER" />
    <user name="guest"    password="35675e68f4b5af7b995d9205ad0fc43842f16450" authorities="ROLE_CLOUD_USER" />
  </user-service>
```

This is causing a conflict. Seeing your configuration, since you are not referring to this bean, please remove it. The error should be resolved.

Comment: But in this example i would like to use two UserDetailsService ; one for the form login, another for the openid login (openIDUserDS)!!  because if i remove the userDetailsService ; i cant login withe for form!! my object openIDUserDS is adapted just for the openid login!! so how i can do?

Comment: Okay, I guess you need this 'userDetailsService' reference in daoAuthenticationProvider (because in dao configuration the reference is put to 'userService', so that was confusing - I think that is a typing mistake while posting). You can configure a userDetailsService with another id as 'userService' as a bean (instead of using user-service tag) and then refer to that in the daoAuthenticationProvider. That should work. You will have to provide an implementation for UserDetailsService.